# Removing repeats in Chart symbology in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, chart

I want use Chart Symbology for my dataset but there are repeats in the chart symbology when I export the map. Pics show what I want and see in Layout view VS the repeat pie charts after I export.

How do I avoid/remove them?

[image]

Comment: What is the ArcGIS Pro version, and I remember reproducing this behavior, did you tried if any other charts(Bar) also gives you the same repeated outputs?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.6. Yes, I tried using Stacked Bar (actually Stacked Bar is the one that I actually want to use) unfortunately there are also repeats. I did not try Bar as it gets a bit squeezy at the middle section.